# PostgresQL - Converting JSON values based on keys, into columns

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, select

Using postgresql,

This is the table I have:

```
id | json
1  | [{"key":"abc", "value":"123"}, {"key":"def", "value":"456"}] 
2  | [{"key":"def", "value":"789"}, {"key":"fgh", "value":"456"}]
```

I'd like to turn it into this

```
id | abc  | def | fgh
1  | 123  | 456 | NULL
2  | NULL | 789 | 456
```

I think the answer lies in between using `json_array_elements`, `array_agg` and some form of nested subquery.

I'm a little confused as to how to apply them in this scenario.

What query can I write for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jsonb_array_elements()` and then use a CASE expression to extract the value if the key is present.

```
select t.id, 
       case when x.element ->> 'key' = 'abc' then x.element ->> 'value' end as abc,
       case when x.element ->> 'key' = 'def' then x.element ->> 'value' end as def,
       case when x.element ->> 'key' = 'fgh' then x.element ->> 'value' end as fgh
from the_table t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(the_column) as x(element);
```

If you aren't using `jsonb` (which you should), use `json_array_elements()` instead.

---

Before you ask: it's not possible to have the column list dynamic. The number, names and types of the columns of a SQL query must be known to the database when it *parses* the statement. They can't be evaluated when the query is executed.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution and it does this instead of desired result above: https://pastebin.com/h4t87dgv

Any thoughts on how to avoid duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery when selecting the all the key values for each row in table:

```
select t.id, 
       (select v.value -> 'value' from jsonb_array_elements(t.js) v where (v.value -> 'key')::text = '"abc"') abc,
       (select v.value -> 'value' from jsonb_array_elements(t.js) v where (v.value -> 'key')::text = '"def"') def,
       (select v.value -> 'value' from jsonb_array_elements(t.js) v where (v.value -> 'key')::text = '"fgh"') fgh
from test t;
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=72f5dd28ca5f4f5be56ae93e7f1614e0).

Comment: `(v.value -> 'key')::text` can be simplified to `v.value ->> 'key'`